# How to add new option to the select dropdown by using the input with hooks?

Tags: reactjs

**Setup:** Two functional components with hooks and a function which can update Parent state from Child component


**Problem:** TypeError if i don't delete line with map:

```
{arr.map(e => {
          return <option key={e} value={e}>{e}</option>
        })}
```

i succesefully get my Parent state in console from `changeStateParent` function, but render crushing.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Parent(){
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(["1","2","3"]);
  function changeStateParent(newArray){
    console.log(arr)
   return setArr(newArray)

  }
  return (
    <div>
      <select name="type">
        {arr.map(e => {
          return <option key={e} value={e}>{e}</option>
        })}
      </select>
      <Child array={arr} change={changeStateParent} />
    </div>
  )}



  function Child (props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    function changeValue(e){
      setValue(e.target.value)
    }
    function update(){
      console.log(props.array)
      const newArr = props.array.push(value)

      props.change(newArr);
    }
    return(<div>
      <input onChange={changeValue} type="text" />
      <button onClick={update}>save</button>
      </div>
    )
  }



const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

**Question:** How to fix that? i can't use lifecycle methods, and can't undestand how to use `useEffect` hook, cause i don't have any events yet.

Comment: So you're trying to add a new option to the select dropdown by using the input?

Comment: Yeap, trying to realize how to do this with hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big issue is that your `update` function is trying to mutate a stateful object, `arr`, which you shouldn't do. Instead, make a copy of that array:

```
function update(){
  const newArr = [...props.array, value];
  props.change(newArr);
}
```

Note that the issue here is `arr.push` was attempting to mutate `arr`, which is deeply frozen due to necessary state immutability.

Comment: Also i can just give to my setValue hook in Child component a fresh new array which i can create from immutable array with spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

I made a basic example [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/poowYgP).

As Nick pointed out, mutating `props.arr` directly was causing that error when your code could no longer map over the array. You can copy it with a spread operator or `Array.from(props.arr)`, or several other ways.

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with `useEffect`, but I added a simple hook that logs the value of the updated array after it changes in the Parent component:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(arr);
  }, [arr])
```

By passing `arr` as a dependency in the array, this function will run every time React registers a change to `arr`, there is no need to use events just to implement a useEffect hook. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: Neither the spread operator nor `Array.from` creates a deep copy; both are shallow copies. In this case that's fine since a shallow copy here is enough to make sure we're not mutating any stateful objects.

Comment: I mean that i can't update the component after state is updated useing `useEffect` hook. i thought about this because my state logging in console from Parent and don't update `<select>` after it (in project i don't get TypeError);

Comment: What do you need to update? You can perform any additional side effects you need to inside of that useEffect call, and they will be run after ```arr``` changes. If you look at the example, it correctly logs the updated state after it updates.